# Receive weekly email digest from feedly?

Tags: rss, rss-reader, feedly

Is it really necessary to have a paid subscription and then take the step of using an IFTTT recipe in order to get your feeds into your inbox?

It seems pretty core to be able to receive a weekly digest of the activity in your feeds (in fact I had sort of expected Feedly to just volunteer this without me even asking since so many other companies love to send out email as early as possible to a new signup)